# Failure in the querySelectorAll() from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem when I try to get a element by using `querySelectorAll`.

Here is the part of HTML that I want to get from JS:

```
<div id="paginacao">
    <div class="pag-base"> <a href="#">{{1}}</a> </div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{2}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{3}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{4}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{5}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{6}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{7}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{8}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{9}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{10}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">...</a></div>
  </div>
```

I'm doing this on JavaScript:

```
var pages = document.querySelectorAll(".pag-base a");
console.log(pages[0].textContent);
```

but this always returns undefined. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to work fine on fiddle.  I'm assuming the '{{#}}' is text and not replaced by some templating engine.  And I'm also assuming your running your command after the markup exists in the dom.

Comment: Yes, seems to work fine.

Comment: Do you run your `JS` **after** the DOM is ready?

Answer (score 0):

that's because the script file is loading before your dom is ready .

try `script tag` below your `div tag`

Comment: Thanks, fella. That solved my problem

Comment: @Flávio glad to help

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with your code.

Everything working as expected, see below

```js
var pages = document.querySelectorAll(".pag-base a"); console.log(pages[0].textContent);
for(var i =0; i < pages.length; i++){
  console.log(pages[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<div id="paginacao">
    <div class="pag-base"> <a href="#">{{1}}</a> </div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{2}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{3}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{4}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{5}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{6}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{7}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{8}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{9}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">{{10}}</a></div>
    <div class="pag-base"><a href="#">...</a></div>
  </div>
```